# webacula - blank screen

Tags: apache, screen, bacula

I have a blank screen while installing webacula and I can't figure out why.
-the login to the mysql database is correct
-Zend library added
-webacula.conf is in /etc/apache2 but returns :
apache2: Syntax error on line 265 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 8 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/webacula.conf: Cannot load mods-available/mod_rewrite.so into server: /etc/apache2/mods-available/mod_rewrite.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

does LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so refers to /mods-available/mod_rewrite.load ? or do I need to add something ?

If anyone knows webacula, contact me and I'll pay you a pint

edit : test_mod_rewrite/testlink1.html returns "mod_rewrite test ERROR"

Answer (score 0):

Did you activate mod_rewrite in Apache ?
You can easily do it with this command:

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```

It should work...

Comment: "Module rewrite already enabled" so no, that's not it :/ thanks anyway